# Automatically changing value in Django

Tags: python, django, web

Good evening!
I am creating an app using Django to manage car rental service. I have a model Car, User and Order, which has a ForeignKey inheriting from Car. I created a form for allowing user creating an order. I want to automatically change the car status as 'Rented' (in Car model it is CharField with 3 choices).
Can somebody help me to solve this problem?

```
class Car(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
    ('Dostępny', 'Dostępny'),
    ('Wypożyczony', 'Wypożyczony'),
    ('Inne', 'Inne'),
    )
    marka = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    production_year = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    id_plate = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=STATUS)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.marka + ' ' + self.model + ' (' + self.color + ')'

class Order(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Klient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_ordered = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    date_return = models.DateField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

That is my form:

```
class OrderForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['client', 'car', 'date_ordered', 'date_return']
```

That's views.py:

```
def createOrder(request):
   form = OrderForm()
   if request.method == 'POST':
     form = OrderForm(request.POST)
     if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('home')
   context = {'form': form}
   return render(request, 'namiejscu/order_form.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a OrderForm you need to also update the car object associate with that form.

So if you are using services to update the data. then you need to call the update query with the care Id from the post request and set it's status.

Otherwise you can add that logic after creating the form and before saving it.

Sample code:

```
def createOrder(request):
form = OrderForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = OrderForm(request.POST)
    car = Car.objects.get(pk=request.POST['car'])
    car.status = "Here put the status"
    car.save()
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('home')
    context = {'form': form}
return render(request, 'namiejscu/order_form.html', context)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but can you please try to help me with this code? I have tried so may options and none of them is working...If you are able to write this update, please.

Comment: @djangoprogrammer edited the answer. Please check if that works for you.

Comment: Do not forgot to verify if the form is valid or not using ```form.is_valid()```!

Comment: @NayanLathiya thank you so much!!! It works perfectly, I only had to add car = Car.objects.get - without objects it didn't work, but thank you for your priceless help!

Comment: Happy to help... updated the answer... missed the objects word there. @djangoprogrammer please accept it as a answer.